# Amending a commit with the effects of hg cp --after

Tags: mercurial

I have a file `before.txt`, which I want to split into two smaller files. What I *should* have done was

```
$ hg cp before.txt part1.txt # Then edit part1.txt
$ hg mv before.txt part2.txt # Then edit part2.txt
$ hg commit
```

Then, both part1.txt and part2.txt will have before.txt as part of their history, so the diff will show as deleting parts of a larger file, rather than deleting one file and creating a new one with some of its contents.

However, what I actually did was

```
$ cp before.txt part1.txt # Then edit part1.txt
$ hg mv before.txt part2.txt # Then edit part2.txt
$ hg commit
```

So before.txt is only present in the history of one of my two files. If I hadn't run `hg commit`, it seems clear to me that I could solve my problem with

```
$ hg cp --after before.txt part1.txt
```

or something similar to that. And I haven't pushed this commit upstream, so I *should* be able to edit it however I like. But I can't figure out how to do it. When I run that `hg cp`, I see:

```
$ hg cp --after before.txt part1.txt
before.txt: No such file or directory
before.txt: No such file or directory
abort: no files to copy
```

This makes sense: it can't record that edit as part of a new commit, because the source file doesn't exist. I *want* to record it as part of the previous commit, but I don't know how to do that except by recording it as part of a new commit and then `amend`ing it into the previous commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to fix that situation:

```
$ hg shelve       # get any miscellaneous, unrelated changes out of the way
$ hg up <parent of revision with the mistake in it>

$ hg cp before.txt part1.txt 
$ hg mv before.txt part2.txt 

$ hg revert -r <revision with the mistake in it> --all
$ hg commit
$ hg strip <revision with the mistake in it>
```

<sub>(I didn't actually try all these commands, hopefully no typos!)</sub>

The first step is optional depending on the state of your working directories.

Now `part1.txt` and `part2.txt` should have the correct contents. The use of `revert` was just to save having to manually re-edit the file changes. But you could also just redo it manually if that seems easier.

The use of revert to pull into the working folder the *effects* of another changeset is a trick I use a lot. Its like a manual way of amending which gives you total flexibility. But it only works well when the revision you are reverting your working copy *to* is closely related to the revision which is the parent of the working copy. Otherwise it will create numerous nuisance changes.

Comment: also notice the `cp` instead of the `mv` to leave file `before.txt` existing and "revertible" without complains

Answer (score 1):

based on @DaveInCaz answer, here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
mkdir tmpdir
cd tmpdir
hg init

echo line1 > before.txt
echo line2 >> before.txt
hg add before.txt
hg commit -m "my before"

cp before.txt part1.txt
hg add part1.txt
hg mv before.txt part2.txt
echo line1 > part1.txt
echo line2 > part2.txt
hg commit -m "my bad"


hg shelve
hg up -r -2

hg cp before.txt part1.txt
hg cp before.txt part2.txt
hg revert -r -1 --all
hg commit -m "my good"

hg strip -r -2
```

some remarks:

- twice `hg cp`, because the later `revert` will delete the file `before.txt` for us, otherwise it would complain about missing it
- `revert --all` at least in my version it requires to specify what is being reverted
- the `hg shelve` is to be safe, before switching over to a different revision
- the `hg up -r -2` could have `-C` since previous `shelve` made us safe, that way you can retry final steps with different approaches and see what suits you better